# sql query with resource = 12 at first and rest of the table shouldn't alter

Tags: mysql

```
id  home  datetime     player   resource
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
1  | 10  | 04/03/2009 | john   | 3 
2  | 11  | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 7
5  | 12  | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 5
3  | 13  | 03/03/2009 | john   | 12
```

what i need is table in below format

**Result :**

```
    id  home  datetime     player   resource
    ---|-----|------------|--------|---------
    5  | 12  | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 12
    1  | 10  | 04/03/2009 | john   | 3 
    2  | 11  | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 7
    3  | 13  | 03/03/2009 | john   | 5
```

Means I need **resource = 12** (if present) at first and then the next rows shouldn't be altered. 
As the above table has resource = 12 so it should come first and then the rest 3,7,5 should be in same order.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line of code in your query

```
ORDER BY FIELD(resource,12) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE resource = 12
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE resource != 12
```